# Google Compute Engine Python API and web API do not return images or kernels

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

When running Google Compute Engine I get unexpected results, different from `gcutil`, when querying images and kernels. Notably I do not get any results.

With `gcutil` I get the expected result of:

```
$ gcutil --project MYPROJECT listimages

+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+
|                              name                              |                          description                           |                    kernel                    | deprecation | status |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+
| projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20130731         | SCSI-enabled CentOS 6; Created Wed, 31 Jul 2013 00:00:00 +0000 | projects/google/global/kernels/gce-v20130603 |             | READY  |
| projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-6-squeeze-v20130723 | Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze) built on 2013-07-23           | projects/google/global/kernels/gce-v20130603 |             | READY  |
| projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20130723  | Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy) built on 2013-07-23              | projects/google/global/kernels/gce-v20130603 |             | READY  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+
```

But when I use the [web API](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/images/list#try-it) or the Python API with something like this (abbreviated, but basically straight from the [examples](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/python_guide#listinginstances)):

```
def _service():
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS, scope=GCE_SCOPE)
    storage = Storage(OAUTH2_STORAGE)
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run(flow, storage)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    auth_http = credentials.authorize(http)
    gce_service = build('compute', API_VERSION)
    return gce_service, credentials, auth_http

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gce_service, credentials, auth_http = _service()
    request = gce_service.images().list(project="MYPROJECT", filter=None)
    response = request.execute(http=auth_http)
    pprint(response)
```

Both the Web and Python API return something like this:

```
{
 "kind": "compute#imageList",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta15/projects/MYPROJECT/global/images",
 "id": "projects/MYPROJECt/global/images"
}
```

i.e. missing the `items` that [one expects in the response](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/images/list).

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google (and public) provided images and kernels are stored in a different project.  The idea is that these aren't *yours*, per se, but instead are published by google (or debian or centos).

You can list kernels with `gcutil listkernels --project=google`.  The equivalent with code is to replace `MYPROJECT` with `google`.

For images, you can use `centos-cloud` for CentOS images and `debian-cloud` for debian images.

`gcutil` automatically integrates from common projects for ease of use.

Comment: Very sensible, many thanks. Wish I had noted that in the docs. Do you know where one would find this and similar info, Joe?

Answer (score 1):

Example app from Google https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/python_guide#listinginstances lists images correctly.
Not sure how code works. You define function _service(opts) with one arguments and then on line 13 you call it with no arguments gce_service, credentials, auth_http = _service()

Please provide working code.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I fixed the code by removing the `opts` argument to `_service`. You may wish to note that listing instances is not an issue here; changing `gce_service.images` to `gce_service.instances` or `gce_service.zones` will produce the expected results - a list of instances. The issue is with kernels and images.

Comment: Brian, sorry about this. So, I've changed 2 lines in Google's example

Comment: I've changed 2 lines in Google's example and got the list of _images_ now. I replaced expression project="MYPROJECT" in your code with my actual project id. running it I also obtained the list of images. So it looks that the problem is not in the API or python libs.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I will look into issues with auth, etc., and post my results here.